# How do I Serialize a JMS Message?

Tags: java, serialization, jms

I am attempting to Serialize a JMS Message so that I can turn it into a BLOB and save it into a SQL database.

My first naive attempt used a Serializable class that took it as a field as follows:

```
private static class SerializableWrapper implements Serializable{
    Message message;
    private SerializableWrapper(Message message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    private Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    private void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
            throws IOException{
        out.writeObject(getMessage());
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        setMessage((Message) in.readObject());
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and continues to throw a `NotSerializableException` for `JMSTextMessage`. I am unsure whether there are other 3rd party libraries that might help to serialize this, but the requirement for my task is to ***not*** have 3rd party dependencies at all.

Is there any good/plausible way to do this without requiring other dependencies?

**Edit:** I am currently achieving this by unpacking every single property and then reconstructing the message as a whole when deserializing. This method is in my opinion still less than optimal - there are some fields that are non-serializable and I also have to separately deal with the various different subclasses of `Message` e.g. `TextMessage`,`ByteMessage` etc.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
            throws IOException{
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap <String, Object> ();
        HashMap<Integer, Object> metaData = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        try {
            Enumeration srcProperties = message.getPropertyNames();
            while (srcProperties.hasMoreElements()) {
                String propertyName = (String) srcProperties.nextElement ();
                properties.put(propertyName, message.getObjectProperty (propertyName));
            }
            //FIXME text/other body not preserved yet, have to preserve the message type eg Text/Byte etc continue after confirming with aditya
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_CORRELATION_ID, message.getJMSCorrelationID());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_DELIVERY_MODE, message.getJMSDeliveryMode());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_EXPIRATION, message.getJMSExpiration());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_TIMESTAMP, message.getJMSTimestamp());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_MESSAGE_ID, message.getJMSMessageID());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_PRIORITY, message.getJMSPriority());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_REPLY_TO, message.getJMSReplyTo());
            metaData.put(KEY_JMS_TYPE, message.getJMSType());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.writeObject(properties);
        out.writeObject(metaData);
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = (HashMap<String, Object>) in.readObject();
        HashMap<Integer, Object> metaData= (HashMap<Integer, Object>) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("JMSMessageUtility - Retrieving Properties: "+properties);
        System.out.println("JMSMessageUtility - Retrieving Metadata: "+metaData);

        Message message = null;
        try {
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new AMQConnectionFactory(CONNECTION_BROKER);
            Destination destination = new AMQAnyDestination(QUEUE_ADDRESS);
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            message = session.createMessage();
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> property: properties.entrySet()){
                message.setObjectProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
            }
            message.setJMSCorrelationID(metaData.get(KEY_JMS_CORRELATION_ID) == null? null:(String) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_CORRELATION_ID));
            message.setJMSDeliveryMode((Integer) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_DELIVERY_MODE));
            message.setJMSDestination(destination);
            message.setJMSExpiration((Long) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_EXPIRATION));
            message.setJMSTimestamp((Long) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_TIMESTAMP));
            message.setJMSMessageID((String) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_MESSAGE_ID));
            message.setJMSPriority((Integer) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_PRIORITY));
            message.setJMSReplyTo(null); // no idea what to do with this
            message.setJMSType(metaData.get(KEY_JMS_TYPE) == null? null:(String) metaData.get(KEY_JMS_TYPE));
        } catch (URLSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setMessage(message);
    }
```

Comment: do you really want all your methods to be private? -- edit: ah, i'm looking at the javadoc. ok got it.

Comment: yeah i'm implementing the Serializable interface, but at a loss as to how the non-serializable field (JMS Message) can be converted as well

Comment: Should you not be serializing the payload of the message rather than the message itself?

Comment: I am trying to save the message as a whole with all its JMS properties in tact so that I can retrieve it from the database and use it again later.  As such it is _not_ just the payload that I need. In fact I'm already extracting the payload and saving it separately.

Comment: Wrapping a non-`Serializable` class in a `Serializable` class doesn't magically make it `Serializable.` You need to serialize it *attributes.*

Comment: Yeah I found out yesterday! See the edit for my attempt on serializing the attributes. However it is quite error prone and inflexible in my opinion

Comment: Mine too, but it's your code. Strange thing to be doing in the first place. If you havent' finished with the `Message,` why remove it from its queue at all? and so why have to persist it somewhere else? Have you considered putting it back *into* JMS somehow for later use?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! What I am trying to do is to save the `Message` into a SQL database, along with some other data that comes along it for erorr logging/debugging purposes. The solution we have implemented currently is similar to what you mentioned and puts the message back into JMS. However, there are other requirements now to enforce policies for putting the message back, as well as error logging needs that have lead us to this solution that we are exploring, which is to save it into a database first before sending it back into the queue.